# Selecting Entire Column minus first several rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, selection

I'm trying to create a template for use with repeatedly generated data. With each worksheet, I need to make several graphs, however, the last row with each worksheet varies. I want to select all the data in a given column, starting with row 14, and continuing to whatever the last row might be. (The header is columns 10-13, and above that is blank.) I've tried multiple ways of doing this, but so far the best I can come up with is selecting the data each time I make the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic range name. For example

```
=Sheet1!$A$14:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH("zzzzz",Sheet1!$A:$A,1))
```

The above formula works for text. For numeric data use

```
=Sheet1!$A$14:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(99^99,Sheet1!$A:$A,1))
```

[image]

You can start the range in any column (change the $A$14 to the desired start address) and it can contain more than one column (the first parameter of the Index() function is the last column of the range), and you can check any column for the last row (the column used in the Match() function).

[image]

When defining the Excel chart, you can use dynamic range names for the Values and the X axis categories.  However, you cannot use a dynamic range name for the "Chart data range" of the data source. Dynamic range names need to be entered individually into the Series and Category dialogs.

For charting purposes, it is best to define one range for the labels (as the one in the first screenshot, then use separate dynamic ranges for each data series column, which can be done with Offset()

```
=OFFSET(ChtLabels,0,2)
```

[image]

When using the dynamic range name in the Series values and the Category labels dialogs, the sheet name must be included in the reference.

[image]

[image]